# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object zombie.Start () (at Assets/scripts/zombie.cs:14)

Tags: c#, c, windows, unity3d

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

я не могу понять что надо делать??????
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZtZ.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: `navMeshAgent = null`!

Comment: На объекте нет HavMeshAgent